# WSO2 Carbon ESB UDP Transport Example

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to setup carbon esb 4.5.0 for UDP transport.

I am using this doc as a guide:  http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/ESB+Samples+Setup#ESBSamplesSetup-ConfigureWSO2ESBforUDPTransport

It says:  "If you wish to use the sample Axis2 client to send UDP messages, you have to uncomment the UDP transport sender configuration in the samples/axis2Client/client_repo/conf/axis2.xml file."

However, looking at the axis2.xml file, there appears to be no commented UDP code.  I see the TCP code, but not the UDP.

Can anyone point me to any resources that I can use to help me with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add transport sender and reciever in axis2.xml. In this scenario ESB's sample client is the sender. Therefore add following samples/axis2Client/client_repo/conf/axis2.xml
 under transport sender configuration.

```
<transportSender name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPSender"/>
```

For Transport receiver which is WSO2 ESB you need to add this in respective axis2.xml's transport receivers section

```
<transportReceiver name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPListener"/>
```

If it is a two way transport use case you need to add both the transport receiver and sender in each axis2.xml.

Comment: Okay, so there is nothing to uncomment then?  Also, are there any working examples of using UDP transports?